# Filter for Camel Restlets

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I am working on camel restlet. I have to do a kind of Authentication/Authorization before allowing the client to access the restlets. Something like check the header for a API key.

How to add a filter, just like we do for Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the reference here?
http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

According to that, you have to define a so-called RestlesRealm.